# Alternative theorem numbering separator

Tags: numbering, theorems

I'm using `amsthm` and I want to have this numbering format for my theorems: **Chapter-Section-Theorem**

The main difference with the default version is the use of "**-**" instead of "**.**" .

Can I do this by defining a new `theoremstyle`?

Comment: Almost certainly possible, but are you using any packages? If so, which ones? Hence the common request for a minimal working example

Comment: @cmhughes, I'm using `amsthm`.

Comment: I solved it myself: \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section] \renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\thesection-\arabic{theorem}} Anybody knows any better solution? Perhaps defining this in my customized class?

Comment: This method will give you theorem numbering of the form `n.m-num`, not `n-m-num`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. In my code I have previously defined `thesection` to reflect `n-m`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{report} % document class that features 'chapter' sectioning level
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\renewcommand\thethm{\thechapter-\arabic{section}-\arabic{thm}}
\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{2}
\setcounter{section}{3}
\begin{thm} aaa \label{thm:aaa} \end{thm}

A cross-reference to Theorem \ref{thm:aaa}.

\end{document}
```